# Understanding source of connection time-out exception

Tags: java, http-proxy

I'm trying to connect to some URL through proxy:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("113.193.248.211", 3128));
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

But I'm getting exception:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

How I can know what exactly throw this exception - connection to proxy server or connection to url defined in constructor of `URL` class?

Comment: This is what stack trace are made for.. You could also put the `new InetSocketAddress` on an other line.

Comment: You can look at the stacktrace, but what I would do in this case is do a `telnet 113.193.248.211 3128`. If that doesn't give a timeout, it's probably the URL which is causing issues.